can migration from loopback v3 to v4 be done incrementally?
I'm exploring how to migrate my application of loopback v3 to v4. I read through the docs https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-overview.html but I'm having trouble to understand:

should my application use typescript to be able to use loopback v4?
there will be changes in my application's booting process, middleware, application mount, datasources, models, and auth. can the migration be done incrementally? e.g. I submit a PR to migrate the models only and deploy this to production, instead of submitting 1 big PR to migrate everything.

thanks
